# My angular ng-table pagination not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm new to angularJS. please help me to slove this issue or give me suggestion link.

I refer this link for my pagination https://gist.github.com/esvit/6821108  but I'm getting error.

my view

```
<div class="row">
  <table ng-table="tableParams" ng-cloak class="table table-bordered table-striped custom-table" ng-hide="data.length==0">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Order Status</th>
      <th>Contact No</th>
      <th>Pensionable</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Assign to a Doctor</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-cloak>
      <td class="custom-td">{{row.id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <td>{{row.email}}</td>
      <td ng-style="set_color(row.OrderStatusColor)">{{row.OrderStatusName}} {{$row.OrderStatusColor}}</td>
      <td>
        <div ng-show="row.primary_phone == 'Mobile'">
          {{row.mobilePhone}} ({{"Mobile"}})
        </div>
        <div ng-show="row.primary_phone == 'Work'">
          {{row.workPhone}} ({{"Work"}})
        </div>
        <div ng-show="row.primary_phone == 'Home'">
          {{row.homePhone}}({{"Home"}})
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="custom-td">{{row.isPensionable}}</td>
      <td class="custom-td"><a href="/DashBoard/ViewDetails?pid={{row.id}}">View Details</a></td>
      <td class="custom-td"><a href="" ng-click="addAppointment(row.id)">Assign</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

and here is my angular code

```
detailsApp.controller("patientCtrl", function ($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.obj = {};
    $scope.changeclass = "col-md-12";
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Dashboard/PatientData" 
    }).success(function (results) {
        $scope.data = results.Data;           
    });  
}

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10
}, {
    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params)
    {
        $scope.users = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
        $defer.resolve($scope.users);
    }
});
```

then i'm getting this error
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Do you know when you ask question and you get answers then either you accept the best answer or ask cross questions about why the given answer is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy table pagination by yourself

```
| limitTo : query.limit : (query.page-1)*query.limit" 
You can use limitTo over ng-repeat of the list or table.

$scope.query = {
   page : 1,
   limit : 20
};

$scope.previousPage = function(){
    $scope.query.page = $scope.query.page - 1;
}
$scope.nextPage = function(){
    $scope.query.page = $scope.query.page + 1;
}
```

And You can put the validation for first and last page.
Add First and last page validations according to you in this methods..

Answer (score 0):

The error the browser is throwing is related to an unknown provider. This error is shown when AngularJS is not able to resolve a required dependency. Make sure you are adding the required JavaScript file (ng-table.js) in your index.html and the **'ngTable'** module as a dependency in the main module of your application:

```
var detailsApp = angular.module('theNameOfYourApp', ['ngTable']);
```

Also, make sure that you are adding the *ng-app="theNameOfYourApp"* attribute to the body tag in your index.html file. This tag is used to **auto-bootstrap** an AngularJS application: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

If you are not using the *ng-app* attribute, then you will need to manually bootstrap the application as it is being used in the example link you provided, and which I don't see in your code:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('demo'), [app.name]);
```

You can check out this link for more info about the Unknown Provider error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

I hope this can help you.

Regards, 
Gerardo.